# C# linq for loop inside the add method

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use for loop inside the add method? 
This is my code and i want to add to each question four answers :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
           Questions.Add(new Question
            {
                QuestionString = GlobalClass.RandomString(40),
                Answers = new List<Answer>() {
                 for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
                  new Answer { } ...
                 }
                } 
            });
        }
```

something like this. I know there are other ways, but just intrested in if it's possible

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(j=>...)`

Comment: How to use it in my code?

Comment: `Answers=Enumerable.Range(0,4).Select(j=>...).ToList()`

Comment: Linq is a query.  That is what the q stands for.  It looks like you are trying to enumerate through a list and add items which is not a query.  It is better in this case to use for loops.

Comment: i've learnt something new thank guys

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    Questions.Add(new Question
    {
        QuestionString = GlobalClass.RandomString(40),
        Answers = Enumerable.Range( 0,4 ).Select( x=>new Answer {
            Id = x
        }).ToList()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, for example you can use mentioned Enumerable.Range

```
new List<Answer>(Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => new Answer { ... }));
```

but please don't use such constructions, it is very hard to debug.